# jquery loop holding last value

Tags: jquery, loops, closures

I have divs with numbered ids that I want to process on the click event:

```
$(function() { 
    for (var i = 1; i != 10; ++i) {
       $("#div" + i).live('click', function () {
           //...
           console.log(i); // always prints 10
       });
    }
});

// html
<div id="div1">...</div>
<div id="div2">...</div>
etc.
```

I was expecting that a click event on each div will fire its own event handler. But that is not the case.

Any fix please.

Comment: use a closure because at time you fired click event i = 10

Comment: `.live` was removed from jQuery in 1.9

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using setTimeout and an integer in a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731759/using-settimeout-and-an-integer-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: can I ask why you're doing it this way?  Can't you just do something like `$('div').on('click', function(){ ...find the div number... });`?

Comment: why using a loop instead of using '[id^=div]' as selector ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a closure:

```
$(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            $("#div" + i).live('click', function () {
                //...
                console.log(i); // always prints 10
            });
        }(i));
    }
});
```

But depending your jquery version, you could use instead .on() (delegation) or .delegate() method using as selector: `'[id^=div]'`

Comment: works well! thanks man!!!! can you point me to a tutorial about closure and delegation please?

Comment: google it and read the DOC, that's the best advice i can give

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 1; i != 10; ++i)
```

for

```
for (var i = 1; i != 10; i++)
```

Comment: This will make no difference

Comment: thanks, but does pre-increment ++i matter? i used to this from C++.

Comment: Can you give a good reason why that's a better practice? Regardless, this should be a comment, not an answer because it doesn't answer the question at all!

Answer (score 0):

The loop is holding the last value because the live event is called after the loop has finished. You need to pass the value to the live event within the loop, as follows:

```
$(function() { 
    for (var i = 1; i != 10; ++i) {
        $("#div" + i).live('click', {i: i}, function (e) {
            //...
            console.log(e.data.i); // prints correct value
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() { 
    $("div[id^=div]").click( function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('div', '');
        console.log(id);
    });
});
```

I find this way of checking for clicks to be much more compact and easier, heres a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9Ckv/) as well, although there are already answers for why your i variable is sticking so feel free to use which ever method seems appropriate.