# How to escape single quotes or double quotes within jquery's append(), onclick(), alert() at one time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping

I have a question when i develop my html with javascript.

What finally I want in html is:

```
<div id="test">
<div onclick="alert("it's a test.")">Show</div>
</div>
```

But in code I want it be realized like this:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
var tmp="it's a test.";//be careful, there must be a single quote in this variable
$('#test').append("<div onclick='alert(\" "+tmp+" \")'>Show</div>");
</script>
```

In firebug it shows:

```
<div id="test">
<div ")'="" test.="" a="" s="" onclick="alert(" it">Show</div>
</div>
```

So i think it's an escaping problem. But I think it has minimum 3 levels of depth.
Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why `onclick=...` when you're using jQuery?

Comment: Because this block of code is in a for cycle. So the code in this page is completely dynamic.

Comment: You use closures then!

Comment: @SalmanA Or the `data` argument of `click`, which makes it simpler (see my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use jQuery to write inlined script. Replace

```
$('#test').append("<div onclick='alert(\" "+tmp+" \")'>Show</div>");
```

with

```
$('<div>').click(function(){ alert(" "+tmp+" ") }).text('Show').appendTo('#test');
```

This way

- you don't eval the code on click
- syntax errors are direcly detected
- you won't have quote escaping problem
- the code is more readable
- you'll have a direct binding, without useless selector resolution
- when you need a variable (for example `temp`), you don't need to put it in the global scope, it can be in the scope of the element addition

To answer your question in comment, you can either

- use an intermediate closure to enclose the value at the time of looping ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731759/using-settimeout-and-an-integer-in-a-for-loop))
- or use the `eventData` argument of [jQuery's click function](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Example of using jQuery's `eventData` argument :

```
var names = ['A', 'B'];
for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
  $('<div>').text('link '+(i+1)).click(names[i], function(e) {
    alert('Name : ' + e.data);
  }).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/UFAMeDiN/1/)

Comment: But what if this block is in a for cycle of an array, and the variable temp depends on the variable in the arry?

Comment: @Luc Then use an intermediate closure to protect it. It will *still* be much cleaner than using code written as string literal.

Comment: My case is more complicated than I described. It's in a li within ul and many div in it. And actually it's an <a> who trigger the onclick. Thank you indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Backslashes can be used to escape special characters

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
var tmp=\"it's a test.\";//be careful, there must be a single quote in this variable
$('#test').append("<div onclick='alert(\" "+tmp+" \")'>Show</div>");
</script>
```

That should work hopefully, if not it should help you get started

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to append new `div` to your `#test` then use event delegation to bind click event for your newly added `div` like this:

```
$('#test').append("<div class='newDiv'>Show</div>");

$('#test').on('click','.newDiv',function() {
    alert("it's a test.");
});
```